# netstat for number of packets received by process IDs

Tags: linux, netstat

I use the simple netstat command "netstat -nltp" which shows me all active TCP connections along with the PID and process name.
However even after playing around with parameters, I am unabe to get an important information from the command.

That is:

I want to see the number of packets received and sent from/to this PID
I learnt that Recv-Q and Send-Q are not indicative of this. Also, the statistics parameter seems to sum up for all processes. How can I see the packets received and sent to a PID?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use inner process counters for that:

```
cat /proc/<PID>/net/netstat
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need it for all "active" processes.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do network traffic accounting per process.

There are number of applications that allow you to do that in real-time (i.e: `nethogs`), but the problem is keeping traffic counters over time.

I would suggest you to do so using `iptables`, assuming you can clearly distinguish your processes using a network port.

This article is still OK for your use case: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-configuring-ip-traffic-accounting/

PS: This sort of questions is best in Server Fault

Comment: Thanks but does iptables show process name/PID info as well?

Comment: No, I stated that I am assuming you can clearly identify your processes based on network port. I suggest iptables because you can have persisted accounting counters across process restart, for example.

Comment: You can easily map ports to PIDs using lsof or netstat